# How to dispaly byte array image/png from controller method(id) on to Asp.net view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

```
public ActionResult Overview(int subId, string countrycod)
{
    byte[] objByteArray =(byte[]) objResponse.Data;
    //return View();
    System.IO.MemoryStream imagestream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    imagestream.Write(objByteArray, 0, objByteArray.Length);
    //return new FileStreamResult(new System.IO.MemoryStream(objByteArray,true),"image/png");
    return new FileStreamResult(imagestream, "image/png");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a memory stream, you could directly return the byte array:

```
public ActionResult Overview(int subId, string countrycod) 
{
    byte[] objByteArray = (byte[])objResponse.Data;
    return File(objByteArray, "image/png");
}
```

And then inside the view use an `<img>` tag that you will point to the `Overview` controller action:

Razor:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Overview", "SomeController", new { subId = 123, countrycod = "en-US" })" />
```

WebForms:

Razor:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Action("Overview", "SomeController", new { subId = 123, countrycod = "en-US" }) %>" />
```